# Mounting Google drive on ubuntu

Tags: google-drive-api, google-authentication

I am trying to mount google drive to Ubuntu.
I am using `google-drive-ocamlfuse`

I got APPID and APPSECRET for drive-api. Everything works fine, I am able to mount using following

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -label $LABEL -id $APIID -secret $APISECRET
google-drive-ocamlfuse -label $LABEL $MOUNTPOINT
```

Problem:
`google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless`  gives a link that needs to opened in browser to get the verification code. Is there a way to get verification code without using browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, which I know works as I have recently done it, is here: [wiki: google drive ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse/wiki/Headless-Usage-&-Authorization)

> (Using a) **web browser on a separate computer**, and ***pasting the results*** into the ***~/.gdfuse/default/config*** (or ***~/.gdfuse/label/config*** if you use labels) of your *headless server*.